# How to append multiple items in one line in Python

Tags: python

I have:

```
count = 0
i = 0
while count < len(mylist):
    if mylist[i + 1] == mylist[i + 13] and mylist[i + 2] == mylist[i + 14]:
        print mylist[i + 1], mylist[i + 2]
    newlist.append(mylist[i + 1])
    newlist.append(mylist[i + 2])
    newlist.append(mylist[i + 7])
    newlist.append(mylist[i + 8])
    newlist.append(mylist[i + 9])
    newlist.append(mylist[i + 10])
    newlist.append(mylist[i + 13])
    newlist.append(mylist[i + 14])
    newlist.append(mylist[i + 19])
    newlist.append(mylist[i + 20])
    newlist.append(mylist[i + 21])
    newlist.append(mylist[i + 22])
    count = count + 1
    i = i + 12
```

I wanted to make the `newlist.append()` statements into a few statements.

Comment: Well obviously it's not the same if you get different results.

Comment: This is invalid syntax.

Comment: Assuming your objects are meant to be lists, your code is not valid Python as you are using `[]` instead of `()`.  Please post real working code.

Answer (score 263, accepted):

No. The method for appending an entire sequence is `list.extend()`.

```
>>> L = [1, 2]
>>> L.extend((3, 4, 5))
>>> L
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: 'insert' functions as 'append' but adds to the beginning of the list. Is there a function to adding multiple values to the beginning of a list?

Comment: @sparrow: No. Slice-assign instead.

Comment: do you need the second input to be a list or can it just be each element separated by commas?

Comment: @CharlieParker: The argument to `list.extend()` must be an iterable.

Answer (score 5):

No.

First off, `append` is a function, so you can't write `append[i+1:i+4]` because you're trying to get a slice of a thing that isn't a sequence. (You can't get an element of it, either: `append[i+1]` is wrong for the same reason.) When you call a function, the argument goes in *parentheses*, i.e. the round ones: `()`.

Second, what you're trying to do is "take a sequence, and put every element in it at the end of this other sequence, in the original order". That's spelled `extend`. `append` is "take this thing, and put it at the end of the list, **as a single item**, *even if it's also a list*". (Recall that a list is a kind of sequence.)

But then, you need to be aware that `i+1:i+4` is a special construct that appears only inside square brackets (to get a slice from a sequence) and braces (to create a `dict` object). You cannot pass it to a function. So you can't `extend` with that. You need to make a sequence of those values, and the natural way to do this is with the `range` function.

Answer (score 5):

You could also:

```
newlist += mylist[i:i+22]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mylist = [1,2,3]

def multiple_appends(listname, *element):
    listname.extend(element)

multiple_appends(mylist, 4, 5, "string", False)
print(mylist)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'string', False]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this :

```
#Inputs
L1 = [1, 2]
L2 = [3,4,5]

#Code
L1+L2

#Output
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

By using the (+) operator you can skip the multiple append & extend operators in just one line of code and this is valid for more then two of lists by L1+L2+L3+L4.......etc.

Happy Learning...:)

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop, it might look like this:

```
for x in [1,2,7,8,9,10,13,14,19,20,21,22]:
    new_list.append(my_list[i + x])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding the same element then you can do the following:

```py
["a"]*2
>>> ['a', 'a']
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple.  Surprisingly in python, you can just use `+=`

myList += newListItems

Example

```
myList = [1,2]
myList += [3,4]

print(myList) # prints [1,2,3,4]
```