# Lists, how to add multiple values at one time

Tags: python, list, tags, append, stack-overflow

i just wondered if there is a way to append at one time multiple values i.e.
defining an function with the parameter x, that will automaticly append the amount of elements definied by an x.

```
def Append(x):
L = []
L.append(x - Elements)
return L
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could add the new elements to their own list, and then just do `L + new_list` Can you also give an example of `x`?

Comment: ``old_list + new_list`` will append two lists together. Try creating a new list of x elements [i for i in range(x)] and adding it to the old list

Comment: Assuming `x` is an integer of however many value you want to add into the list, all your function is doing is appending the result of `x - Elements` into the list, presumably an integer or a `TypeError`.  If what you want is say to append the integer `0 to x` You might want to look into `list.extend(range(x))` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append multiple items in one line in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621498/how-to-append-multiple-items-in-one-line-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Try this to append several similar values to an existing list:

```
>>> l = [1,2]
>>> l += [3]*2
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 3]
```

.extend() list method works too

```
>>> l = [1,2]
>>> l.extend([3]*2)
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

i meant it to add an x-Amount of Elements, not an specific one but just for example: Append(20) -> Should add 20 new elements